# Intuition for matrix representation of deterministic sinusoidal cycle

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-analysis

In [Jalles2009pg5](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6242335.pdf) they represented the determnistic sinusoidal cycle

$ \Psi_t = \alpha \cos(\lambda t) + \beta \sin(\lambda t),\quad t=1,2,\ldots$

via the recursion

$ \begin{bmatrix} \Psi_t \\ \Psi_t^* \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\lambda) & \sin(\lambda) \\ -\sin(\lambda) & \cos(\lambda) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Psi_{t-1} \\ \Psi_{t-1}^* \end{bmatrix}$

with $\Psi_0 = \alpha$ and $\Psi_0^* = \beta$

I can algebraically derive that this works (the form at [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Matrix_form) basically gets you there). But this still sort of seems like magic to me. I'm missing the bigger picture of why this works.

**Question**: Can anyone provide an intuitive explanation of why this works and, maybe, how this generalizes/simplifies?

Comment: Are you just asking "why does $\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\lambda) & \sin(\lambda) \\ -\sin(\lambda) & \cos(\lambda) \end{bmatrix}$ represent a rotation by $\lambda$ radians?"?

Comment: @Ian I guess so. Been a while for me. Looked up "rotation" matrix. Good material at [What's the intuition behind a 2D Rotation Matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852530/whats-the-intuition-behind-the-2d-rotation-matrix) and [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)